# Is is possible to delete Recently Closed Tabs without deleting Safari history?

Tags: ipad, safari, ipados, browser-history

I'm using an iPad 6th gen running iPadOS 16.X.

I want to delete my Recently Closed Tabs "history", but I still want to keep my Safari history. To open my recently closed tabs, I have to press and hold the "+" key.

[image: Screenshot showing Recently Closed Tabs]

[This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/427551/488400) answer explains how to delete Recently Closed Tabs, but it requires me to delete my history. Online results are showing similar solutions, so not working for me.

My question is therefore : **Is it possible to delete recently closed tabs in Safari and still keeping my history, and if so, how?**

Comment: Not sure what you want to do here? What is the benefit of removing something from your recently closed tabs, but not from history?

Comment: @nohillside There are less recently closed tabs items that there are in history. I often use the pin option in Safari and therefore close tabs quite rarely. But since I noticed that the recently closed tabs are showing very old websites that I've visited months and months ago, I want to delete them to be able to really be careful at what I delete. Also, since I'm pinning tabs and staying on them, all the pages I go to on those tabs get saved in my history when nothing really useful is saved in recently closed tabs. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On iOS, clear Safari history without discarding open tabs?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373332/on-ios-clear-safari-history-without-discarding-open-tabs)

Comment: @Allan No, this is not what I'm looking for, the question is about deleting Safari history. And if you read the title of my question, you should understand that I want to delete recently closed tabs WITHOUT deleting Safari history.

Comment: The answer is still exactly the same:  there is an issue with closing tabs and its relation to history entries.

Comment: „Recently deleted“ shows the last page visited in recently *deleted* tabs, and is not related to recently *visited*. Still fail to see what problem you are trying to solve here, the entries don‘t cause any issues.

Comment: @Allan It's not because they are related that they are the same and necessitate the same answer. I don't have any issue with closing tabs, I just want to delete recently closed tabs (see screenshots) **without** deleting Safari history. In the question and you provided, the OP wanted to delete Safari history without **closing** tabs. It's not the same at all, the only relation is that we are both talking about Safari history and tabs (not even tabs because I'm talking about recently closed ones).

Comment: @nohillside Yes, recently closed tabs are a kind of history (not really but-) of tabs you recently closed. I want to clear recently closed tabs "history" but keeping the normal Safari history of recently consulted sites. Is it clearer? :)

Comment: Tabs are tabs, @thinkr. Whether they are recently closed or not doesn’t change the issue with the closing of a tab removes history and deleting history removes those tabs.  They are linked for some reason and it’s a known issue.  It’s just one of the myriad reasons I use anything but Safari.

Comment: @Allan I agree on this point but still persist at affirming that the question and answer you proposed does not answer my question. Also, why would the closing of a tab remove history?

Comment: As stated in my comment and in the answer, ***there is an is an issue where the two are linked***. I gave you the answer, you could write it up and potentially get upvoted.

Comment: Encapsulate comments in asterisks like regular posts.  One asterisk = *Italics*; two = **bold**; three = ***bold italics*** .

Comment: I understand *what* you want to accomplish, I fail to understand the *why*. Why is important to „cleanup“ recently closed tabs? Knowing this might make it easier to find alternative solutions.

Comment: Be judicious with it  because overuse will end up having the opposite of your intended effect.  Also, @nohillside poses a very valid and helpful question you should address.

Comment: @nohillside I want to do this because when I will need to share this iPad with my friend (his is broken) and I don't want his to snoop around in my recently closed tabs. I have there some links to drive.google.com files and documents with my work when I was smaller and I don't want him to come and see my archives. Note: These links aren't in my history anymore because it deletes after 3 months.

Comment: Ah, you probably could just visit Apple.com first in a tab you want to close. But of course this doesn‘t work for tabs already closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Not possible.

You cannot suppress Recently Closed Tabs without deleting Safari history.

Recently Closed Tabs are intricately linked with Safari history, and clearing Safari history entries deletes: (1) the tabs, and (2), the Recently Closed Tabs «history».

Furthermore, there is no other option than deleting Safari history to delete recently closed tabs in Safari or in Settings.

This is one of the rare issues with Safari and I hope there will soon be an option to make users able to clear that recently closed tabs «history».

### But...

I just found a way to delete the most recent closed tabs.
*This only works in custom Tab Groups*.

You need to **create a Tab Group** (or open one if you already have some).

[image: Screenshot when creating a custom Tab Group]

Then, it should open the Tab Group on Start Page (Safari's home page). Click on **Edit** and make sure **Recently Closed Tabs** is enabled. Now, click on the "X" at the top left of the "Customize Start Page" dialog window to close it.

[image: Screenshot of the Customize Start Page window in Safari]

When you will close a tab, it will show up in the *Recently Closed Tabs* section in your Start Page as well as in the Recently Closed Tabs (when you long-press on the + button next to the address bar).

**Before clicking on "Clear All"** :

[image: Screenshot or Recently Closed tabs before clicking 'Clear All']

Then, click on "**Clear All**", this should make the "Recently Closed Tabs" section in your Start Page disappear. But, it will also make the elements in that section also disappear in Recently closed tabs (when you long-press on the "+" button)!

[image: Screenshot of the 'Clear All' button in Start Page]

**After clicking on "Clear All"** :

[image: Screenshot of Recently Closed Tabs after clicking 'Clear All']